# Assistance running simple select statement against multiple databases SQL2008 R2/2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Great site here, been reading up no how to acomplish this task, but so far unsuccesfull in using the sp_MSforeachdb stored procedure.

My Select statement:

```
Select
--count(VisitProcedureUid)
name
from dbo.VisitProcedure
WHERE ISPERFORMED = 'FALSE'
```

Would love for this to total out against all database with that table (all but Master/timetracker)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for finding all tables named `'employee'` in all databases.

```
USE master

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
'
use [?]

select 
"?" as DBNAME
,name
from sys.tables
where name like "%employee%"    
'
```

as you can see that you need to wrap `select` statement in single quotes, than inside the statement include `use [?]` which is forces the code to be executed against each DB.